# Reading from a text file and attempting to use printWriter to write to another results in a blank file

Tags: java, io, printwriter

My assignment is as follows:

> to write a program that reads the attached text file and writes out a separate text file (using your first initial and last name as the filename).  The new text file should contain all the same lines of text as the input file with the addition of a line number appended as the first character on the line.
>
> Ex: if your input line reads:
>
> this is a test
>
> your output should read
>
> 1. this is a test

I've written what I believe is mostly functional code- upon running it compiles and creates a new file to be written to, but that file is blank (contains 0 bytes). Reading up on the problem, I tried making sure my printWriter and input/output streams were closed/flushed. I'm not sure at this point whether something is wrong with my loop or if I'm calling the close methods in the wrong place. Any help is appreciated.

Code is as follows:

```
package module6lecture;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ReadWriteProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Reid\\Desktop\\Chapter11.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Reid\\Desktop\\rulicny.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fis);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while(scan.hasNextLine());
        {
            String stringRead = scan.nextLine();
            pw.println(lineNumber + ": " + stringRead);
            lineNumber++;
        }
        pw.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnf)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to find Chapter11.txt. Exiting...");
        fnf.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Disclaimer: I am a total newb.

Comment: Try adding multiple printlns in your code to see if places are being reached. Most importantly, the write line.

Comment: Seems like you have the exact same assignment as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456696/modify-contents-of-text-file-and-write-to-new-file-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is semicolon right after you while loop

```
while(scan.hasNextLine());
//                       ^
```

which makes it infinite loop because it represents empty instruction, just like

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){}
```

so you are never actually entering

```
{
    String stringRead = scan.nextLine();
    pw.println(lineNumber + ": " + stringRead);
    lineNumber++;
}
```

block, and code after it which means you are not writing anything to your result file and you don't even close it. All you have if empty file created with

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Reid\\Desktop\\rulicny.txt");
```

So remove this semicolon.

---

BTW you can easily spot this kind of mistakes if you will let your IDE format code for you. Eclipse formatted your example for me as

```
while (scan.hasNextLine())
    ;
{
    String stringRead = scan.nextLine();
    pw.println(lineNumber + ": " + stringRead);
    lineNumber++;
}
```

which as you see shows it quite good that your loop actually executes empty statement instead of code block.

Comment: This seems to have solved one problem. The output file is being printed to, but it simply prints the first line of the input file in an infinite loop. What do I need to do to get the scanner to read the lines in sequence instead?

Comment: Strange, after removing this additional semicolon your code works fine for me. Consider sharing current version of your code (but don't change your original question since it would make answers incorrect) by posting it for instance on pastebin.com.

Comment: I tooled around with it a little bit more and then decided to try undoing all my changes to the point where I was right before deleting the semicolon, deleted it again, and lo and behold, as you say it works perfectly. Not sure what I changed but thank you very much regardless!

Answer (score 0):

Try predefining `String stringRead` outside of the loop.